# SQL запрос чтобы объединить вывод из двух таблиц

Tags: php, sql

Есть, к примеру 2 таблицы

```
base:
id
name
adress
country_id

countries:
id
country
```

Между ними есть связь country_id - id.
Как написать запрос так, чтобы при выводе таблицы base было значения поля country, а не просто идентификатор country_id

Answer (score 1):

```
select base.name, base.adress, base2.country 
  from base 
 inner join base2 on base.country_id = base2.id
```

Comment: спасибо) разобрался

Answer (score 1):

```
select base.name, base.adress, countries.country 
from base as b left join countries as c
on  b.country_id=c.id
```

в предложенном решении

1. выводится только имя, адрес базы и страна, при этом ИД базы и страны не выводится,
2. если случится, что в таблице стран нет страны с таким ИД, как указано в таблице баз, то в поле страна будет выведен null